# How do Favored Classes work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, multi-classing, character-levels

So, I am creating my first Pathfinder character ever right now together with some friends. We are all new at this.

I figured I'd go for a half-elven Cleric. 
Everything good so far.
But! The two favored classes option confuses me. I didn't find anything specific about them in the core rulebook. How exactly do they work? Are they just an inherent option that gives you bonuses if you level up in a class, regardless of whether you pursue it or not or do they count as a choice of class? Multiclassing lvl 1 upwards is kind of a weird idea and I am sure I must have gotten something wrong.

Thank you all in advance!
-derhoques